# Script in /etc/profile.d prevents me from logging in, is it possible to fix it?

Tags: login, profile

OS: Zorin

I put a .sh script into /etc/profile.d to fix an issue I had with an application. The script was this

```
nautilus . &
killall nautilus
exit 0
```

Now when I try to log in, I just get returned to my login prompt. I tried doing it through the terminal, but had the same issue of course. Is there a way to fix this, maybe remove the script or prevent it from running, or do I have to reinstall my OS? I am new to linux, so I was oblivious to what would happen.

Comment: Do you have another user on the system? Can you boot from a live Linux USB?

Comment: @terdon I do not have another user on the system. And I do not know what the latter is. I do have a usb with a zorin os iso. Can I set up a live linux USB with another pc? I have a windows laptop which I can use to do that.

Comment: @terdon I'll just do a fresh install. Next time I do something with start up stuff I'll first test it out in a vm

Comment: There really is no need to do a fresh install! Please undelete and ping me.